# ggplot2 plot that evaluates the percentage and mean of a third variable at intersecting points

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data set of a list of patients, two categorical variables, an outcome, and a length of stay. A sample of that data is as below:

```
ID,A,B,Outcome,LOS
1,5,4,Died in Hospital,20.9
2,4,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,2096.47
3,5,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,1258.25
4,2,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,337.37
5,5,4,Died in Hospital,8.13
6,5,4,Died in Hospital,17.53
7,5,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,904.02
8,4,3,Died in Hospital,1425.9
9,5,4,Died in Hospital,21.77
10,2,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,1017.3
11,5,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,1009.08
12,1,3,Discharged Home,573.25
13,5,4,Died in Hospital,170.97
14,5,4,Died in Hospital,85
15,5,4,Discharged Home,476.65
16,5,4,Died in Hospital,42.48
17,5,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,1512.35
18,1,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,777.77
19,2,4,Died in Hospital,1104.75
20,3,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,699.08
21,4,4,Died in Hospital,1859.93
22,5,4,Discharged Home,781.73
23,5,4,Discharged Home,477.42
24,4,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,1424.47
25,5,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,1284.98
26,5,4,Transferred to rehab facility,1783.27
27,2,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,886.82
28,2,4,Died in Hospital,577.85
29,5,4,Discharged Home,549.98
30,4,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,2271.1
31,5,4,Died in Hospital,169.82
32,5,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,736.82
33,5,4,Died in Hospital,548.7
34,5,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,481.67
35,4,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,887.18
36,3,4,Discharged Home,674.63
37,4,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,1600
38,5,4,Died in Hospital,50.1
39,2,4,Died in Hospital,169.85
40,5,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,1595.85
41,5,4,Died in Hospital,8.15
42,2,4,Discharged Home,371.37
43,5,4,Died in Hospital,26.13
44,5,4,Died in Hospital,196.42
45,5,4,Died in Hospital,117.38
46,5,4,Died in Hospital,263.78
47,5,4,Discharged Home,613.22
48,2,4,Discharged Home,255.85
49,5,4,Died in Hospital,37.05
50,3,4,Discharged Home,2052.55
51,5,4,Died in Hospital,51.95
52,4,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,714.12
53,3,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,687.05
54,1,3,Transferred to other acute hospital,1411.37
55,4,4,Discharged Home,445.12
56,2,4,Discharged Home,233.08
57,5,4,Transferred to other ICU,137.07
58,2,4,Discharged Home,346.73
59,5,4,Died in Hospital,96.88
60,4,4,Discharged Home,511.43
61,5,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,1067.02
62,5,4,Discharged Home,810.68
63,1,4,Discharged Home,385.98
64,3,4,Died in Hospital,457.73
65,2,3,Discharged Home,684.37
66,4,4,Discharged Home,475.68
67,3,4,Discharged Home,2693.92
68,3,4,Discharged Home,333.58
69,1,4,Discharged Home,249.32
70,2,4,Discharged Home,282.3
71,1,3,Discharged Home,573.22
72,1,2,Discharged Home,441.98
73,1,3,Discharged Home,396.48
74,1,3,Discharged Home,886.4
75,2,4,Discharged Home,651
76,3,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,967.57
77,4,3,Discharged Home,557.23
78,1,2,Transferred to other acute hospital,473.37
79,2,4,Discharged Home,399.85
80,2,4,Discharged Home,495.7
81,1,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,779.83
82,2,4,Discharged Home,301.42
83,3,4,Died in Hospital,562.37
84,3,4,Discharged Home,2589.27
85,3,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,700
86,5,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,763.57
87,3,4,Discharged Home,584.85
88,2,4,Discharged Home,705.72
89,1,3,Discharged Home,581.08
90,2,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,565.3
91,2,2,Discharged Home,306.25
92,2,2,Discharged Home,468.7
93,3,4,Discharged Home,344.8
94,4,4,Discharged Home,319.28
95,2,3,Discharged Home,427.6
96,2,1,Discharged Home,244.42
97,4,3,Discharged Home,405.22
98,3,3,Died in Hospital,398.7
99,1,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,607.2
100,2,4,Discharged Home,470.98
101,2,2,Discharged Home,325.22
102,1,3,Discharged Home,448.72
103,4,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,499.55
104,2,2,Transferred to other acute hospital,473.7
105,2,4,Died in Hospital,908.2
106,1,3,Discharged Home,372.77
107,2,3,Discharged Home,360.63
108,1,3,Discharged Home,303.63
109,1,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,2797.98
110,2,4,Discharged Home,588.75
111,4,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,1078.32
112,3,3,Transferred to other acute hospital,350.55
113,5,4,Died in Hospital,106.83
114,1,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,851.58
115,1,2,Discharged Home,342.47
116,3,3,Discharged Home,517.67
117,2,4,Discharged Home,2117.82
118,3,4,Discharged Home,610.68
119,2,3,Discharged Home,561.47
120,2,3,Discharged Home,359.87
121,1,2,Discharged Home,473.95
122,5,4,Discharged Home,832.12
123,1,4,Discharged Home,396.97
124,1,4,Transferred to rehab facility,859.65
125,1,2,Transferred to other acute hospital,585.97
126,4,4,Discharged Home,494.37
127,3,3,Died in Hospital,157.87
128,3,4,Discharged Home,358.18
129,2,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,1001.02
130,1,1,Discharged Home,334.82
131,2,2,Discharged Home,269.98
132,2,2,Discharged Home,326.5
133,1,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,496
134,1,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,362.35
135,1,2,Discharged Home,226.82
136,1,2,Transferred to other acute hospital,517.1
137,2,3,Discharged Home,330.87
138,1,3,Discharged Home,308.82
139,1,1,Discharged Home,428.63
140,1,3,Discharged Home,239.25
141,3,4,Discharged Home,389.92
142,1,1,Discharged Home,187.32
143,1,3,Transferred to other acute hospital,167.02
144,1,2,Discharged Home,300.4
145,1,1,Discharged Home,155.57
146,1,2,Discharged Home,218.13
147,2,3,Discharged Home,446.57
148,1,2,Discharged Home,132.55
149,2,2,Discharged Home,258.37
150,2,3,Discharged Home,298.18
151,1,1,Discharged Home,176.38
152,1,4,Discharged Home,723.37
153,1,1,Discharged Home,542.2
154,1,1,Discharged Home,329.43
155,2,3,Died in Hospital,120.18
156,1,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,207.9
157,2,2,Discharged Home,246.75
158,1,3,Discharged Home,308.87
159,2,2,Discharged Home,122.4
160,1,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,1440.27
161,1,2,Discharged Home,332.28
162,1,2,Discharged Home,224.18
163,1,3,Discharged Home,256.65
164,3,4,Discharged Home,939.55
165,2,2,Discharged Home,809.87
166,1,3,Discharged Home,335.62
167,1,3,Discharged Home,285.93
168,1,4,Discharged Home,9319.17
169,2,3,Discharged Home,328
170,1,3,Discharged Home,235.78
171,1,2,Discharged Home,215.55
172,1,4,Discharged Home,421.65
173,1,2,Discharged Home,258.5
174,1,3,Discharged Home,347.48
175,1,3,Discharged Home,327.73
176,1,4,Discharged Home,265.37
177,1,2,Discharged Home,107.37
178,2,3,Discharged Home,236.17
179,1,2,Discharged Home,180
180,1,2,Discharged Home,84.3
181,1,2,Discharged Home,133.87
182,1,3,Discharged Home,311.03
183,1,2,Discharged Home,305
184,1,3,Discharged Home,400.3
185,1,3,Discharged Home,324
186,1,1,Transferred to other acute hospital,427.12
187,1,2,Discharged Home,284.62
188,1,4,Died in Hospital,235.73
189,1,3,Discharged Home,173.55
190,2,3,Discharged Home,339.6
191,1,2,Discharged Home,448.65
192,1,3,Transferred to rehab facility,252.8
193,1,3,Discharged Home,374.4
194,1,3,Discharged Home,180.52
195,1,4,Discharged Home,403.33
196,2,2,Transferred to other acute hospital,56.97
197,1,2,Discharged Home,378.07
198,3,1,Discharged Home,350.07
199,1,1,Discharged Home,293.07
200,1,2,Discharged Home,67.67
201,1,3,Discharged Home,81.6
202,2,3,Discharged Home,436.35
203,1,2,Discharged Home,276.27
204,3,4,Discharged Home,658.08
205,1,2,Transferred to other acute hospital,266.2
206,1,1,Discharged Home,280.97
207,1,4,Discharged Home,324.07
208,2,3,Discharged Home,293.85
209,1,2,Discharged Home,425.32
210,1,3,Discharged Home,185.77
211,1,4,Transferred to other acute hospital,87.75
212,1,3,Discharged Home,170.28
213,1,4,Discharged Home,352.6
214,2,3,Transferred to other ICU,8.25
215,2,4,Discharged Home,382.15
216,1,4,Discharged Home,429.13
217,2,2,Discharged Home,375.03
218,2,4,Discharged Home,1157.8
219,1,2,Discharged Home,410.93
220,1,1,Discharged Home,343.03
221,1,2,Discharged Home,324.55
222,1,1,Discharged Home,120.55
```

I am trying to make a plot with A and B as axes, at at each combination of A and B display the percentage who die of that combination. In another plot, I am trying to make a plot with A and B as axes, at at each combination of A and B display the mean length of stay for that combination.

For example, at B=4 A=2, there are a total of 24 patients, 4 of whom died. I would then want to display 4/24 = 16.7% at that point.

I have tried with stat_sum (which has been very useful in the past for similar things, but I have not found it useful here.

The code I have tried is:

```
dx$died <- ifelse(dx$Outcome=="Died in Hospital", 1, 0)
bubbleDeath <- ggplot(dx, aes(x=B, y=A)) +
stat_sum(aes(group=1, weight=died, label = paste(round(..prop.. * 100, 2), "%", sep = "")), geom = "text", show_guide = FALSE)
print(bubbleDeath)
```

This has not worked, as it evaluates it as a group, not as an individual point. I have played with a ddply but got nowhere!

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dplyr` (not `ddplyr`) to summarise your data thus:

```
require(dplyr)
dxtab = hosp %>% group_by(A,B) %>% 
   summarise(died = sum(Outcome=="Died in Hospital"), n=n(), pc=100*(died/n))
```

then `ggplot` to the rescue:

```
ggplot(dxtab, aes(x=A, y=B, label=sprintf("%2.2f",pc))) + geom_text()
```

[image: plot percentages]

Add `stay=mean(LOS)` to the summarise to get that measure too. `dxtab` looks like this:

```
   A B died  n        pc      stay
1  1 1    0 12  0.000000  301.5908
2  1 2    0 28  0.000000  301.2882
3  1 3    0 29  0.000000  372.9076
4  1 4    1 23  4.347826  990.2161
5  2 1    0  1  0.000000  244.4200
6  2 2    0 12  0.000000  336.6450
7  2 3    1 15  6.666667  348.7973
8  2 4    4 24 16.666667  638.7075
9  3 1    0  1  0.000000  350.0700
10 3 3    2  4 50.000000  356.1975
11 3 4    2 18 11.111111  905.7672
12 4 3    1  3 33.333333  796.1167
13 4 4    1 14  7.142857 1048.3586
14 5 4   19 38 50.000000  503.0453
```

Comment: Thanks - this is incredibly helpful! As a follow-up, how would I go about doing more formal stat summaries by those combinations (i.e. 95% confidence interval, SD, etc.)?

Comment: I think you should compose another question - we can't really answer supplementary things in comments...

Comment: Never mind :) - for those ever interested, dxtab$error_str=qnorm(0.95)*sd(dxtab$stay)/sqrt(dxtab$n)

Answer (score 2):

This generalizes the solution and also uses a heatmap instead of just plain text:

```
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

dat_sum <- dat %>% 
  mutate(A=factor(A), 
         B=factor(B)) %>%
  group_by(B, A, Outcome) %>%
  summarise(outcome_total=n()) %>%
  mutate(freq=outcome_total/sum(outcome_total)) %>%
  merge(expand(., B, A, Outcome), all.y=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(outcome_total=ifelse(is.na(outcome_total), 0, outcome_total),
         freq=ifelse(is.na(freq), 0, freq),
         fill_col=cut(freq, 
                      breaks=seq(0,1,.1),
                      include.lowest=TRUE))

dat_sum %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=B, y=A)) +  
  geom_tile(aes(fill=fill_col), color="#7f7f7f") +
  geom_text(aes(label=percent(freq), color=fill_col)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", brewer.pal(n=9, name="BuGn"))) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(rep("black", 6), rep("white", 3))) +
  facet_wrap(~Outcome, ncol=3) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank()) +
  theme(strip.background=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Aye. I missed a few lines when copying the data file. I updated the plot.